# Send to bech32 segwit address from Bitcoin Core 17.1

Tags: bitcoin-core, segregated-witness, bech32-address

I have a non-HD wallet in Bitcoin Core v17.1.  I have never used SegWit before.

I need to send some coins to a bech32 address from bitcoin-qt GUI.  The problem is after selecting the specific coin inputs to use (originally received into P2PKH address), and then entering the bc1... bech32 send to address, then the Send button does nothing.  I usually after pressing Send button get a passphrase prompt to unlock the wallet and confirm sending the transaction.

How do I send to a bech32 address from qt GUI?

Comment: This sounds like a bug that's unrelated to bech32 addresses.

Comment: Maybe it's a bug related to the selected inputs.  I'll upgrade to 18.0 soon and try again.  I'm also running on some older Linux qt libraries.

Comment: When I upgraded bitcoin-qt, the problem was fixed.  Bug in 17.1